# How to tell whether a user can invite a particular friend to an event

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

The graph api allows you to invite multiple friends to an event by using `POST EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER1,USER2,etc.` However the entire POST will fail if **one** of the friends in the comma delimited string has blocked this user from inviting him to an event.

The problem is that it does not tell you which friend(s) failed.

Thus making the multiuser POST totally **useless** unless we can find out which user is the offending user.

Comment: I guess if the list is long, you could still get through by spliting it in halfes and doing a "binary search" to get it all through. Expect log(n) instead of n calls (even though 2 calls would be a lot better)

Comment: A binary search with each iteration making and a network connection and then some code to invite everyone else who did not fall into the search pattern sounds like a little bit of an overkill for a simple REST operation.

Comment: Agreed, but if there is no way of getting the API to tell out what element causes the rejection the binary approach gives you less requests and not that much extra logic to it compared to a direct iterative approach.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#invited),

> You can invite users to an event by issuing an HTTP POST to /EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID. **You can invite multiple users by issuing an HTTP POST to /EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,USER_ID2,USER_ID3.** Both of these require the create_event permission and **return true if the invite is successful**.

So what exactly does

> However the entire POST will fail if one of the friends in the comma delimited string has blocked this user from inviting him to an event

mean in your problem description – are you “just” getting *false* as an answer, with the requests to the other users actually being send – or does *none* of the users receive their invite, even though only one of them blocked it?

The first outcome would be annoying; the second one totally a bug IMHO.

Comment: *none* of the users receive an invitation if *one* of the users has blocked invitations from your user.

Comment: Definitively worth making a bug report then: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs